# Change VECTOR_OUTLINE Color in playn

Tags: java, playn, tripleplay

I am trying to create  a label with a black outline in playn with triple play. This code creates a label:

```
new Label("Label").addStyles(
    Style.COLOR.is(Color.white.getRGB()), 
    Style.OUTLINE_WIDTH.is(5f),
    Style.TEXT_EFFECT.is(TextEffect.VECTOR_OUTLINE)
)
```

but I have no idea how to change the outline color. The only style settings for `VECTOR_OUTLINE` seem to be `OUTLINE_WIDTH`, `OUTLINE_CAP` and `OUTLINE_JOIN`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Style.HIGHLIGHT` to specify the outline color.